# Word 2010 add style to Quick style gallery NOT showing alias name

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, styles

I have Headings 1 through 8 in my quick style gallery, but the alias names are showing instead of Heading 1, Heading 2, etc. This would typically be handy, but the alias names defy logic and only exist so text brought in from other documents map over to the correct heading style in the new document.

I thought of making macros that apply the heading styles and adding those to a new tab, but that seems like overkill.

****Edited based on comment

Here is what I see:
[image: Quick Styles - no good]

Here is what I want to see: [image: Quick Styles -preferred]

My styles pane looks like this: [image: Styles pane showing headings with aliases]

Comment: Some screen shots would help us understand your question. Upload any image(s) to [Imgur](http://www.imgur.com) and you will get link(s) you can share. [Edit] your question to include the link(s) and someone with sufficient reputation will inline the image(s) for you.

Comment: If you add a first alias in front of the PRT etc, being the Heading style without a space, so:  Heading 1,Heading1,PRT and repeat all the way through you'll keep your styles in the right order and it'll look almost the same as Heading 1 etc.

Comment: That is actually very reasonable. Clever. I want the user to know that they can still use the default shortcuts for their headings and that would likely do the trick.

Comment: I am new and do not know how to give Tanya credit for the answer. If you know, please let me know.